# passing values in UIalertview

Tags: iphone

i need to pass 1 variable in single alert view.....for example.... i need to pass the username as "john videos deleted"

i write the code as

```
    self.myAlert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"MNB" message:@"Video deleted Successfully" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil] autorelease];
```

Comment: anybody understood the question?

Comment: please ask proper way we can't understand what exactly you want.

Comment: do you want to display anything on the alertview from the variable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *str = @"John";

self.myAlert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"MNB" message:[NSString strinWithFormat:@"%@ video deleted successfully",str] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1):

The view controller the opens the UIAlertView should keep this variable not the AlertView.